# Android Google Play services

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, google-play-services

I developed an Android app using Google Play Service, to use GCM service.

In MainActivity check the device for a compatible Google Play services APK before accessing Google Play services features. In the app this check is done in two places: in the main activity's onCreate() method, and in its onResume() method. like this:

```
if (checkPlayServices()) {
    // If this check succeeds, proceed with normal processing.
    // Otherwise, prompt user to get valid Play Services APK.
    ...
}
```

and :

```
private boolean checkPlayServices() {
int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
    if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(resultCode)) {
        GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, this,
                PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST).show();
    } else {
        Log.i(TAG, "This device is not supported.");
        finish();
    }
    return false;
}
return true;
}
```

My Problem is : in some country users can't download Google play service from GooGlePlay, so they can't use my app.

is it possible to put google play services on app ? or put it on another server and prompt user to download Google Play Services from new location ?

any other solution are welcome.

Best Regards,

Answer (score 4):

Even with Google Play Services libraries, you will still need it installed on your device. [`GooglePlayServicesUtil`](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesUtil.html#getErrorDialog(int,%20android.app.Activity,%20int)) is specifically for checking Google Play Services (if installed, version, etc).

Call `isGooglePlayServicesAvailable()` to check if you have it installed and if so, what version. If the resutCode is **not** a success, then call `GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog()` and pass it the error code. This should prompt the user to install Google Play Services.

Comment: in some country Google play is not available in Google play, So users can't install them.